# How path is equivalent to url in django 2.0 in terms of wild card characters?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Django. However, that tutorial is using url() function inside url.py rather than path. I was checking documentation about path() but I am a bit confused.

Like, what is the equivalent of raw string search for

```
url(r'^admin/$', 'views.about')
```

in path

like how ^ and $ wild card characters are mapped in the path() function.

Comment: `url` function is not deprecated yet. You can still use it while following the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

`django.urls.path()` function is a simpler, more readable syntax.

Lets take an example of how we write `url()`:

```
url(r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.bio)
```

Now the same url logic can be written using `path()` as

```
path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
```

So you can see that `path` is much simpler to understand since there is no regex involved.

To write regex you need to use `re_path`

```
re_path(r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.bio, name='bio')
```

From the documentation about `url()`

> This function is an alias to django.urls.re_path(). It’s likely to be
> deprecated in a future release.

Hence you try to use `path()` and `re_path()` instead of `url()`

Comment: and also, **`url()`** function is still accessible as **`from django.conf.urls import url`**